# Extracting/loading a Unix .nightly file using Windows

Tags: mysql, unix, webserver, gzip

I'll say now that my description is likely to be full of inaccuracies, but in essence that's why I'm here lol

I've received a back-up of my organisations old website from our old supplier and I'd like to get it up and running locally. They sent 2 files, one contained all the old Drupal 6 site files and I have no problem with those as I'm comfortable migrating drupal based sites, however that file contained no database backup. The second file was compressed (.gz) and within that was another compressed/archive/snapshot file with a .nightly extension. This file I cannot open and my best guess is its a snapshot of the Unix server the old site was running on and therefore would at least have the DB.

My experience with Unix is very limited as the company I work for uses Windows servers only, so I tend to run Apache on them, but basically I have no idea how to do anything with this .nightly file and the old supplier is no longer replying to any emails as we are no longer paying them for a service.

Just hoping some here might have an idea of what I can do to get at the information.

Again, sorry for my poor description.

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to a Unix server? It sounds like this is something proprietary by your old supplier.

If you have access to a Unix server, then copy the file to it, extract it using gunzip, and then I'd suggest using some of the following commands to try and identify the file type:

> file FILE_NAME
>
> head FILE_NAME
>
> strings FILE_NAME

If you get any information from that, you can try searching the internet using that info.